# Creating popup menu like in gmail

Tags: android, popup

Does anyone have a clue what the best procedure would be to show a menu like this one on the left where you have only icons shown, but when you click on the top "three lines icon" you extend this view over another fragment?

I currently have 2 fragments in a activity shown, like this second and third one on the image, but would like to add that left bar but don't know what would be the best thing to do. Thanks in advance for any info!

[image]

Comment: You can do a `Custom ListView` with an `Adapter and Object` then later on the `Layout Items` put only `ImageViews` with the icons and don't put textViews.

Comment: I think this may be a `DrawerLayout`, but I am unsure how to make it partly visible like the image.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't do exactly what I wanted, only fragment that gets it's weight changed, so I still don't have a "popup" like fragment but currently it's ok. I will still try to find a way to do it like I wanted